# Lamps To Use For Natural Outdoor Lighting With Animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been creating a lot of outdoor scenes with nature. The problem I run into is the lamp choice for outdoors especially for animations. I always start with a sun, but it ends up being too bright in one small area,  and the surrounding isnt bright enough. What lamps/settings should I be using to make everything seem relatively lit equally but also realistically?

Comment: For realism try HDRI (high dynamic range image) and Environment lighting, with or without lamps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/realistic-outdoor-lighting-in-cycles/5319#5319 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5875/should-i-add-a-sun-lamp-when-using-an-hdri-environment

Comment: @cegaton One of the post says that HDRI's are bad for animations. Also what do you mean by environment lighting?

Comment: The idea is that you don't use lights to illuminate the scene, but an High dynamic range image that's attached to the world environment (think of it as an image wraps 360 degrees around your objects). The reflections and luminosity are calculated using the values of such image (as if your objects were indeed part of such "environment") http://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2011/11/cycles-setting-image-based-lighting-ibl.html

Comment: @user2593789 There is nothing wrong with using an hdri/environment texture *for lighting* in an animation, but if you use objects in the texture as part of your scene, moving the camera will not give the desired effect (as the texture is 2D).