# Glossy materials not rendering correctly

Tags: materials

I'm new to blender (and 3D modelling) so please use dummy terms if you answer!

I have applied 3 materials one each to 3 different objects and only 1 renders the same as the material preview. I've attached a screenshot to show you what I mean. The silver material should be on the top ball and the brass material should be on the cylinder holding the ball up. I've no idea why it's not working when the copper material on the spiral wire worked. I'm using cycles render if that helps?

[image]

Comment: You have no enviroment to reflect. That is why it is so dull.
Add envrimonet map or model some eviroment.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15683/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23111/599

Comment: @JozefCulen feel free to add an answer based on your comment. It would be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something to reflect. 
Currently you have white plane on the ground and grey sky. That is exactly what your material reflects.

You need to add enviroment map or sky texture.