# Gray plastic bottle material (w/ label) needs to be more transparent and clear

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor

Tried adding a brightness / contrast node after the glass but it did nothing to make the gray glass more clear. In fact it made it black. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Lighting [matters a *lot*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23906/599), especially with [glossy](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15683/599)/[refractive](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23111/599) materials. In addition, you are mixing the glass directly with a diffuse shader, making the glass uniformly 50% diffuse. I imagine you only want the label to be diffuse. In that case, see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8706/599).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just discovered that by adding the gray alpha button from the Image Texture to the Mix Shader's gray Fac button was the perfect solution!

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct if you wish!