# Make a reflective surface

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am designing a copper top of a flag post.

How do i make the surface texture reflective, so that it can reflect every object and light in the environment?

Comment: How do you intend to use the texture in your shader? Could you specify which render engine are you using? What have you tried so far? Can you show something?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/glossy-materials-not-rendering-correctly

Comment: I use the ultimate shader from engine 2.79. In the right pane, i tried to change the material. The item to reflect is a round skynode.

Comment: You mean a metallic shader?

Comment: Do you intend to do something similar to an environment cue map? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles

Answer (score 4):

[image]

- Enable cycles render and add a new Principled BSDF material for your object.
- Set metallic to 1.
- Find the correct base color for your metal.
- Adjust roughness based on how sharp or blurry you need the reflections to be.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my question: My sprite engine does not support Cycles at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are two selection boxes to set to make reflection available. I'll show this on Blender 2.79

Properties -> Scene -> Shading -> Ray Tracing should be enabled.

[image]

Properties -> FlagPostTopObject -> Material -> Surface -> Shading

should have some value, or else you don't get the

Properties -> FlagPostTopObject -> Material -> Surface -> Mirror

pane on a fresh install of Blender.

Properties -> FlagPostTopObject -> Surface -> Mirror should be enabled.

You can pick the color to reflect. 
To make the surface fully reflective you set the Reflectivity to one.
Depth is the maximum number of times a ray is reflected, if you have for example two mirrors facing each other. The reflection of light that the Fresnel equations predict is known as Fresnel reflection, but the zero you see in my screenshot next to Fresnel, is no physical constant. You can set it to two and the reflection diminishes.
To make the material look like copper, you will have to experiment a little.

[image]