# How can i make my material look like more like a crystal glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to make a crystal-like material but i cannot find out how...i added a Glass BSDF with Transparency, plus some transparent background made with the Holdout option in Nodes...but still, it just looks like Plastic, but not a crystal...
Does anyone know a good solution for this? Maybe add more transparency via Mix Shader? i'm sure there are other better options..
[image]

Reference

[image]

Comment: This tut may interest you: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-cave/

Comment: most shiny and glass materials depend largely on the environment they reflect.

Comment: Thanks, but the tutorial didnt worked for me or at least isnt what i need :/ and this scene does not have any enviroment because it needs to be totally black/transparent

Comment: @beavoru You can have an *Environment Texture* for the *World Background* and still render the background as transparent. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hmm, i don't know if thats the solution because i already tried that before but it didnt help..
i edited the question now, with a reference :)

Comment: You just need to add more details to your scene. Maybe make the roughness a little sharper as well.

Comment: You may want to also look up some photographer advice how to shoot glass.. mainly how to setup the studio environment and how to position lights..its all the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering a Water Drop in Cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/rendering-a-water-drop-in-cycles)